# Using Google Maps to display Search Results

Tags: android, ios, google-maps

I've been searching all up and down google trying to find this as well as SO. I just want a simple url that will display 1) The person's current location and 2) All search results in that area pertaining to the search string that I supply. So it would look something like this preferably.

> http://maps.google.com/maps?location=currentlocation&radius=500&keyword=food

Where the keyword food is any search string that I would like placed in there. I need this to be a url that can be opened in both iPhone and Android (at the very least iPhone). I plan on opening it in a webview or the maps app.

Also yes I have tried plugging in long/lat in place of current location as well and still couldn't get it working. And I know that I will probably end up having to get their long/lat in code and using that, I just want the area search portion to work. If you have any ideas on how to get what I'm trying to accomplish I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the link I get from Google Maps when I search food.

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=food&hl=en&sll=40.796934,-73.949232&sspn=0.018924,0.023174&hq=food&t=m&z=16
```

It seems to break down like this:

Base URL

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?
```

Search Term

```
q=food
```

Position

```
sll=40.796934,-73.949232
```

Span

```
sspn=0.018924,0.023174
```

Zoom Level

```
z=16
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting it to work in my browser. I'll try and integrate it and see what I get. Thanks again.